# Excel Spinner Button to Update Cell on Another Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, spinner

I am looking to use a Excel spinner button on my first worksheet to update the value of cell on the second worksheet.  The address of the cell to be updated is a variable based on a value chosen in a dropdown menu on the first worksheet.  I keep getting errors - can this be done?  [Link to Excel file in question](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/0k85j947en6nx1m8pey6t/ProjectSiteIDGenerator.xlsm?dl=0&rlkey=j2pgjz8b0r0l21fdl0zx4sod6)

```
Private Sub SpinButton1_Change()

cell = Range("G2").Value
cellText = "Reference!" & cell   'Here I am trying to concatenate another worksheet named "Reference" and the cell range to be updated on that worksheet


Range(cellText).Value = SpinButton1.Value  'Here I am trying to use that concatenation to update the value of the cell on the second worksheet.


End Sub
```

The error I am receiving is:

```
'Runtime error 1004':
Method 'Range' of object' '_Worksheet' failed
```

Comment: If you are getting errors, it's helpful to include details of those errors in your post.  Also, the first thing that I would confirm is that the value of "cell" is actually a valid range reference itself.  Just pop a MsgBox (with "cell") and see what it's value is.  It could be that you're ending up with the "cellText" value being a bad reference string that Excel can't interpret

Comment: The value of the object "cell" is a variable, but that variable always is a cell address (i.e. A1, B4, etc.)

Comment: By my question, I meant what is the *specific* value of `cell` when the error occurs, i.e. what is the output in the Immediate Window of `Debug.Print cell`.

Comment: The specific value is G4

Comment: No repro. Did you actually check the output in the Immediate Window? I find it better to use something like `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reference").Range(cell)` to refer to a range.

Comment: Added the error message to the original question.  Runtime error 1004.

Comment: @BigBen your suggested code gives the error:  'Runtime error 9, Subscript out of range'

Comment: That means `ThisWorkbook` doesn't contain a sheet named Reference.

Comment: Its definitely there.  Am adding dropbox link to file....

Comment: That tab name is misspelled `Referenece`.

Comment: I feel stupid about that - though I didn't create the tab, I should have noticed.  I am able to create a button that changes the value and got the spinner button working as well using ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reference").Range(cell).Value as the reference.